# Error: Missing multiplication operator, missing or unbalanced delimiters. To construct matrices, use brackets instead of parentheses

Tags: matlab

am trying to design an interface using the MATLAB APP DESIGNER. However, I am getting an error message.

This is for creating a user interface in using MATLAB APP DESIGNER

```
% Callbacks that handle component events
    methods (Access = private)
        % Code that executes after component creation
        function startupFcn(app, varargin)
            % Configure image axes
            app.ImageAxes2.Visible = 'off';
            app.ImageAxes.Colormap = gray(256);
            axis(app.ImageAxes, 'image');
            app.ImageAxes3.Visible = 'off';
            app.ImageAxes.Colormap = gray(256);
            axis(app.ImageAxes, 'image');

        end
        % Callback function
        function DropDownValueChanged(app, event)

            % Update the image and histograms
            updateimage(app, app.DropDown.Value);
        end
        % Callback function
        function LoadButtonPushed(app, event)

            % Display uigetfile dialog
            filterspec = {'*.jpg;*.tif;*.png;*.gif','All Image Files'};
            [f, p] = uigetfile(filterspec);

            % Make sure user didn't cancel uigetfile dialog
            if (ischar(p))
               fname = [p f];
               updateimage(app, fname);
            end
        end
```

I expected the user interface to be displayed after running the simulation. But I am getting the following error message:

```
"Missing multiplication operator, missing or unbalanced delimiters. To construct matrices, use brackets instead of parentheses".
```

The errors point to the line that uses the METHODS function. However, that particular line in MATLAB APP DESIGNER code view is gray in color. As a result, I am unable to edit that particular line. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What comes before `methods`? There is supposed to be a `classdef` line above it somewhere.

Comment: the classdef comes at the beginning of the code. there is a separate function before METHODS.

Comment: My comment was meant to encourage you to post complete code. Can’t tell you what’s wrong if I can’t reproduce the problem. See [mre]. Also, if you post a question, you should stick around for a bit and check in regularly to interact with the people willing to help. Answering a comment a week later...

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I am sorry for being late to respond to your question. I want to upload the complete code. But I am not seeing any option of doing that. can you let me know about uploading the full code here.

Comment: Don’t upload your full code, create a [mre], the minimal, complete code that I can copy-paste from the question and run on my machine and see the error you are seeing. Typically you don’t need a whole lot of code to reproduce the error. But it is a bit of effort to make. As an added bonus, when you create the minimal example you often end up discovering the problem by yourself. You can [edit] the question at any time to improve it.

Comment: By the way: I’m asking for more code because I suspect that is the code above the bit you show here that is the problem.

Comment: function updateimage(app,imagefile)

% For corn.tif, read the second image in the file
if strcmp(imagefile,'corn.tif')
    im = imread('corn.tif', 2);
else
    try
        im = imread(imagefile);
    catch ME
        % If problem reading image, display error message
        uialert(app.UIFigure, ME.message, 'Image Error');
        return;
    end
end